# Can anyone help me solve this diophantine equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all integer solutions to $x^2 + 7 = 2^n$. I've done the case where n is an even integer but now I'm a little lost. Could anyone walk me through the solution?

Comment: As well as $n=4$, you have solutions for $n=3,5,7,15$.  The difficult part is checking for larger $n$

Comment: This is the Ramanujan-Nagell Equation. See https://oeis.org/A060728.

Comment: I never knew it had a name, thank you!